# Calculus: A given sequence $(a_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ with the property that $a_n\cdot a_{n+1}=1$ .

Tags: calculus

Calculus: A given sequence $(a_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ with the property that  $a_n\cdot a_{n+1}=1$ .

1. Find all the partial limits of the series $(a_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$.
2. Given $(a_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ a converges. Find the limit of the series.

***Attempt***:

Unfortunately, I have no idea

$a_n\cdot a_{n+1}$ need to be equal to $1$

Option 1: if all the sequence equal to $1$ ?

Comment: Try writing down some examples of such sequences. It should not be too difficult. (Whenever you "have no idea," try to play with examples. That's a good rule to follow all over mathematics.)

Comment: Try to answer the second part first.

Comment: What does the phrase "The sustain for..."  mean?

Comment: @WillJagy Exists for I edited.

Comment: No, edit again. You should say "with the property that" $a_na_{n+1}=1$ as part of the one sentence.

Answer (score 1):

That's pretty close to trivial isn't it?  Let $a_1= a$.  Then $a_1\cdot a_2= a(a_2)= 1$ so $a_2= \frac{1}{a}$ $a_2\cdot a_3= \left(\frac{1}{a}\right)a_3= 1$ so $a_3= a$.
$a_3\cdot a_4= \left(a\right)a_4= 1$ so $a_4= \frac{1}{a}$.

See a pattern? You can *conjecture* that $a_n= a_1$ for n odd and $a_n= \frac{1}{a_1}$ for n even.  Can you prove that for all n?

Comment: thanks, if $a_n =n$ for $n$ odd and $a_n= \frac{1}{n}$ for $n$ even we can see that $n\cdot a_n= \frac{1}{n}=1$ for all n  right? , and the partial limits of the series is $0$ and $\infty$ right?